# Select by attributes alternative

Tags: query, select, select-by-attribute

I have a huge list of parcel data that I need to assign land use values. The criteria is such that if more than one land use type overlays a parcel, then I need to assign the parcel with the land use that covers it the most (i.e., has the highest **LU_Pct**). Here’s an example of what my attribute table looks like:

[image]

I tried doing this by using Select by Attributes, but it didn’t work. I also tried to use the summarize function which allowed me to find the maximum **LU_Pct** for each **Parcel**, but it wouldn’t carry over the corresponding **LU_Type** record in the final output.

Does anyone know how I can find the maximum **LU_Pct** for each **Parcel** that will also carry over the **LU_Type** in the final selection or output feature (polygon)? I apologize if I'm overlooking something very basic!

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: Massive overkill but reliable. Sort original in descending other of numeric field. Delete identical from it using parcel I'd. Transfer land use back to parent using parcel ID for join

Answer (score 1):

Use the summarize function for the parcel-column with maximum-function and safe it as a new table.

Join this table to your original table via the parcel-cloumn. You now get the LU-Type that has the maximum-value for each parcel.

That you need to dissolve by the column you got from the summarize-table.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a summary table of max LU_pct for each Parcel
2. Join the summary table to the original table using the parcel ID from each table as the join field
3. Select all records where parcel.LU_pct = summary.MAX_LU_pct
4. (optional) Remove the join
5. Export or create a table view of the selected records

This will leave edge cases where you have parcels with identical max percentages of two or more landuses. This has occurred if the # of selected records in step 3 > the # of parcels. These could be identified with a second summary table on the results of step 5.

Comment: If the LU_pct is calculated from the spatial data (not entered by hand) and only rounded for display purposes, the edge cases should be extremely rare.